# VBA- Create a checkbox where options are dynamic based on remove duplicates performed

Tags: excel, vba

How do I create a checkbox selection in vba that is dynamic? In my procedure, I first look at my very long excel sheet and I remove duplicates to get the unique values. I want my userform to have checkboxes whose options are the unique values I just found.

Comment: re: *'In my procedure, ...'* - In **what** procedure? I see no procedure.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have a listbox?  With checkboxes you'll need to add a new checkbox for each item, make sure there's some kind of click event linked to that checkbox, etc, etc.... with a listbox you could just use a dynamic named range.

Comment: Agreed with @Darren. Avoid a selection of checkboxes and just go with a listbox. 10 times easier for a dynamic range.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you would create a checkbox dynamically upon initializing a form.

```
  Dim chkBox As Control
  Set chkBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "chkCheck", True)
```

I suggest you take a look at

http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/free-training/ExcelVBA2/excelvba2lesson21.htm